# Global declaration of a symbol of a given size

Tags: assembly, nasm

There is such a code example on *nasm*:

```
section .text
global _start:function (_start.end - _start)
_start:
...
.end:
```

How does such a `global _start` declaration of a symbol differ from such a `global _start:function (_start.end - _start)`
And what does "Declare as a function symbol with the given symbol size." mean?

Comment: See the [nasm manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.5). TL;DR: _"ELF object files can contain more information about a global symbol than just its address: they can contain the size of the symbol and its type as well. These are not merely debugger conveniences, but are actually necessary when the program being written is a shared library."_

Comment: @Jester, If I don't specify the size of the symbol and use the linker, can I not specify the size of the symbol?

Comment: @prostargamer If you do not specify a symbol size, the size will be 0.